# anchor and hash values issues

Tags: jquery, hash, anchor

I have the following code:

```
<ul class="questions">
<li><a href="#test1">test1</a></li>
<li><a href="#test2">test2</a></li>
<li><a href="#test3">test3</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="test1">test1 text</div>
<div id="test2">test2 text</div>
<div id="test3">test3 text</div>
```

i use this script to highlight the wanted id anchor in the same page :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() 
    {
        $('a').click(function(event) {

           $(location.hash).css("background-color","red");


        });
    });

});
</script>
```

the anchor movement works but the  highlight for the selected id don't work unless i refresh the page after the page load from the first time and also the current highlight  don't disperse when i click another link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function() {});
```

is a shortcut for

```
$(document).ready(function(){})
```

so, as Alexander said, you don't need both.

If the highlight does not work, you could try:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
       $($(this).attr("href")).css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

since you can't rely on the location that change after the click event.
There is jQuery plugins that allow to add events to "on hash change", that could be a solution for you if you use it a lot.

edit: It's normal that the current highlight doesnt disappear when you click another link.

```
$(function() {
    $(location.hash).addClass("red");
    $('a').click(function(event) {
       $(".red").removeClass("red")
       $($(this).attr("href")).addClass("red");
    });
});

.red { background: red; }
```

Comment: missed setting the color on page-load

Comment: hello your code work perfectly just change $("a.red").removeClass("red")
to $(".red").removeClass("red")

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the anchor's **href** is applied **after the onclick event** of the anchor is handled. Hence **during the click event** handling the **hash of the location is not changed yet**.

You can instead rely on the href attribute to change the color:

e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function() 
                    {
                            $('a').click(function(event) {
                                var divID = $(this).attr("href");
                                $(divID).css("background-color","red");
                            });
                    });
    </script>
```

Comment: that's work too but i need it also for external documents so the hash of the location may change

Comment: When you say external documents, wouldn't ht epage navigate to those documents on clicking the anchor?

Comment: I'm really not sure if your way work too with external pages i have to try it .

Comment: Am not saying it will work with external pages. If your page gets redirected to an external page you will have to make use location.hash on the page load of the external page. I mean in page load you can have something like " $(location.hash).css("background-color","red"); " (I assume the link will include the # for external links)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() 
    {
        $('a').click(function(event) {

           $(location.hash).css("background-color","red");


        });
    });

});
</script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


        $(function() 
        {
            $('a').click(function(event) {

               $(location.hash).css("background-color","red");


            });
        });

    </script>


// This is a shortcut...
$(function() {});

 // for this...
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

Comment: That should be `jQuery(function($){});` to correctly alias `jQuery` to `$`.

Comment: @Alexander: That's true, but it doesn't fix the issue. Nesting `.ready()` calls is ultimately harmless because `.ready()` also works if the DOM is already "ready".

Comment: @zzzzBov: jQuery aliases itself to `$` automatically.  `$(function() {});` is correct.

Comment: @zzzzBov: jQuery is correctly aliased by default, but I'd agree that your approach is a nice safeguard.

Comment: @Rocket @patric dw, its only aliased to `$` if `noConflict` is **not** called. If you ever port your code as a plugin, or to a page with additional frameworks, it's easier to *not* re-write all your `doc.ready` events.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() 
  {
    $('a').click(function(event) {
      $(location.hash).css("background-color","red");
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I'll start from the top:

Make sure to enclose your script in `CDATA` tags to prevent XML encoding issues:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
...code...
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

`$(document).ready(...);` is the same as `$(function(){});` which many others have noted. What most people fail to realize is that it's designed to alias `jQuery` to `$` (or whatever other name you'd prefer) to prevent namespacing conflicts:

```
jQuery(function($){
  ...code...
});
```

When the `document.ready` event has fired, there is no instance where you tell the current hash value to be highlighted:

```
$(hash).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Ok, so I'm using a variable named hash because there's no guarantee that the hash is set or that it will begin with a '#' sign (I'm looking at you IE).

```
function normalizeHash()
{
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash.length)
  {
    if (hash[0] != '#')
    {
      hash = '#' + hash;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    hash = '';
  }
  return hash;
}
```

because you want to toggle the colors off when another hash is set, you should be using classes

CSS:

```
.activeHash
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

JS:

```
$(hash).addClass('activeHash');
```

You'll need to remember to remove the classes from elements during the click function:

```
$('.activeHash').removeClass('activeHash');
$(hash).addClass('activeHash');
```

@Cybernate caught an issue I missed: the hash wont have changed until *after* the click event, the simple solution is to get the `href` of the anchor element, although this assumes that the `href` isn't written with the path (a work-around would be to also listen for the hashchange event):

```
hash = $(this).attr('href');
```

So to put it all together:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

function normalizeHash()
{
  var hash = location.hash;
  if (hash.length)
  {
    if (hash[0] != '#')
    {
      hash = '#' + hash;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    hash = '';
  }
  return hash;
}

jQuery(function($){
  var hash = normalizeHash();

  $(hash).addClass('activeHash');

  $('a').click( function(e){
    hash = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.activeHash').removeClass('activeHash');
    $(hash).addClass('activeHash');
  } );
});

/* ]]> */
</script>
```

<sub>Disclaimer: I didn't test any of this code, let me know if I've made a tyop of speeling mistak.</sub>

Comment: hello it seems every thing works normal except it need to click the link twice to show the red background

Comment: @user602720, @cybernate caught an issue I missed. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: i also  notice you code work fine with ff ie8 but with ie6 and ie7 give error like this error : exception thrown and not caught ,line 20

Answer (score 0):

this the final code that works globally thank you all for your quick responded
i Appreciate it :)

> ```
> <html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
> ```
>
> lang="en">
>
> ```
> <script src="jquery.js"></script>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
> <style type="text/css" media="screen">
>
> .red { background: red; }
>
> </style>
> </head>
> <body>
> <ul id="con">
> <li><a href="#test1">test1</a></li>
> <li><a href="#test2">test2</a></li>
> <li><a href="#test3">test3</a></li>
> </ul>
>
> <div id="test1">test1 text</div>
> <div id="test2">test2 text</div>
>
> <span id="test3" >
> <div>
> dvdvdvdvdvdvdvdvdvdv
> </div> 
> </span>
>
>
>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>
> $(document).ready(function() {});
> {
> $('#con a[href*=#]').click(
> function(){var elemId='#'+$(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];highlight(elemId);});
>
> function highlight(elemId)
> {
> $(".red").removeClass("red")
> $(elemId).addClass("red");
>
> }
> if(document.location.hash){highlight(document.location.hash);}
> }
>
> </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: [You don't need to post a thank-you answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq); instead, you should click on the check-mark next to whichever answer has helped you find your solution.